# how to add 2 vertical field managers on third vertical field manager in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

[image]

Hi please tell me how to make this screen in blackberry.
my data is not adding on it.i took vertical field manager to add all components.

Comment: this can be done in a single vertical field itself. why you go for 3 ?

Comment: i have images for different panels and i have to set that in this manner thats why i am going in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working.. I created it for you. use this code

```
public class home extends UiApplication {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    home app = new home();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}

MainScreen screen = new MainScreen();
private int deviceWidth = Display.getWidth();
private int deviceHeight = Display.getHeight();
LabelField lbl1 = new LabelField("label");
final Bitmap backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg1.jpg");
final Bitmap backgroundBitmap1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg2.jpg");
final BitmapField mybitmapField = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("facebook-logo.jpg"),DrawStyle.HCENTER);

public home()
{
    super();
    pushScreen(screen);

    VerticalFieldManager mainManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR )
        {          
            public void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.clear();
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, deviceWidth, deviceHeight, backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);                       
                super.paint(graphics);
            }            
        };
      //this manger is used for adding the componentes
    VerticalFieldManager subManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR )
        {
            public void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.clear();
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, deviceWidth, deviceHeight, backgroundBitmap1, 0, 0);                       
                super.paint(graphics);
            }   
        };

        screen.add(mainManager);
        mainManager.add(lbl1);
        mainManager.add(subManager);

        subManager.add(mybitmapField);
        subManager.add(new LabelField("Data 1"));
        subManager.add(new LabelField("Data 1"));
        subManager.add(new LabelField("Data 1"));
}   
}
```

output will be like this. 
[image]

Comment: ya absolutely same thing i have done.but only either data is displayed or image is displayed.both are not displayed.any another way to show it??

Comment: Arun Kumar Munusamy ,really Thank YOU ,You guys are really too helpful that's why i can learn BB.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Find an example of how to make this screen below:

```
    VerticalFieldManager manager = new VerticalFieldManager();
    VerticalFieldManager first = new VerticalFieldManager();
    VerticalFieldManager second = new VerticalFieldManager();

    first.add(label);
    second.add(image);
    second.add(data);
    second.add(data);
    second.add(data);

    manager.add(first);
    manager.add(second);
    add(manager);
```

Comment: I AM SORRY Farid,but i want to add data in same panel on which i am adding image .Data must be shown  below of image.but now only one of them is displayed.how to displayed both.